# in my case toString() method in javascript accepts argument . where , on the MDN its different info?

Tags: javascript

```
function createRandomId() {
    var i, random;
    var uuid = '';
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        random = Math.random() * 16 | 0;
        if (i === 8 || i === 12 || i === 16 || i === 20) {
            uuid += '-';
        }
        uuid += (i === 12 ? 4 : (i === 16 ? (random & 3 | 8) : random)).toString(16);
    }
    return uudi;
}
```

So in the above function we are creating a random id number. In for loop when we adding id to the global `uuid` variable we using `toString()` method which accepts one argument. but when I read MDN doc([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)) they mention that this method should not accept argument .

so I am confused here in my case why this method accepting a argument and also working with that?

Comment: toString method accepts an argument, which is radix. say if you want to convert a number to its binary form, you can just toString it with radix 2.
`var decimal = 5;
decimal.toString(2); // 101`

Comment: You're not looking for the base `Object.prototype.toString`, you're calling it on a number: look at the documentation for [Number.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong MDN page. The value on which `toString` is being called on in your code:

```
(i === 12 ? 4 : (i === 16 ? (random & 3 | 8) : random)).toString(16)
```

is a *number*, not an object.

[Number.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) does indeed accept one argument:

> Syntax
>
> numObj.toString([radix])
>
> Parameters
>
> radix
>
> Optional. An integer in the range 2 through 36 specifying the base to use for representing numeric values.

Were your code to have an *object* there - just, for example

```
uuid += { foo: random }.toString(16);
```

then the 16 in `toString(16)` would indeed be meaningless.

Comment: exactly what i wanted to convey in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a number to a string representation in base 16 effectively becomes the hexadecimal version of the number.

More here: [click here for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)